# Consolidating multiple columns into one column in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data-frame that looks something like"

```
print(dat)
A  B  C
1  NA NA
NA 1  NA
1  NA NA
NA NA 1
```

Reproducible by:

```
dat <- data.frame(A=c(1,NA,1,NA), B=c(NA,1,NA,NA), C=c(NA,NA,NA,1))
```

So that if a 1 is found in given column the other two columns will have NAs.  I am trying to consolidate this information into 1 column so it looks like:

```
print(dat)
A
B
A
C
```

I have tried:

```
dat<-ifelse(dat$A==1,"A",ifelse(dat$B==1,"B",ifelse(dat$C==1,"C","NA")))
```

But it does not work.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Comment: Reproducible data frame: dat <- data.frame(A=c(1,NA,1,NA), B=c(NA,1,NA,NA), C=c(NA,NA,NA,1))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
rep(names(dat),nrow(dat))[c(t(dat)) == 1 & !is.na(c(t(dat)))]
[1] "A" "B" "A" "C"
```

Answer (score 3):

`max.col` is the winner for these sorts of tasks:

```
colnames(dat)[max.col(!is.na(dat))]
#[1] "A" "B" "A" "C"
```

Comment: Winner winner chicken dinner.  It seems like you, akrun, and me are the only ones that ever use it ;)

Answer (score 2):

Another way:

```
> t(dat) %>% melt() %>% na.omit() %>% select(X1)
   X1
1   A
5   B
7   A
12  C
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is

```
names(dat)[+(!is.na(dat)) %*% seq_along(dat)]
#[1] "A" "B" "A" "C"
```

Answer (score 1):

To add to the existing options, try:

```
na.omit(stack(dat))$ind
## [1] A A B C
## Levels: A B C
```